# dynamic array in c++: valgrind leak

Tags: c++, valgrind, destructor

I'm trying to implement a dynamic array in c++. once it becomes full, its size is doubled and is copied to the double-sized array.
it looks fine but Valgrind says I have a leak.
I should say that I'm not allowed to use any of c++ STL structures- that's why I'm using new[] and delete[] operators.

this is my code:

```
template<class T>
class DynamicArray
{

    int size;
    int numOfElements;
    T* arr;

public:
    DynamicArray(int size) :
            size(size), numOfElements(0)
    {
        arr = new T[size];
    }
    ;

    int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    int getNumberOfElements()
    {
        return numOfElements;
    }

    void insert(T element)
    {
        arr[numOfElements++] = element;
        if (numOfElements == size)
        {
            T* extended_array = new T[size * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++)
            {
                extended_array[i] = arr[i];
            }
            delete[] arr;
            arr = extended_array;
            size = size * 2;
        }
    }

    T& operator[](int i)
    {
        if (!((i >= 0) && (i < size)))
            throw arrayOutOfBoundsException();
        return arr[i];
    }

    ~DynamicArray()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    class arrayOutOfBoundsException: std::exception
    {
    };
};
```

My main program is:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void printIntArray(DynamicArray<int> arr){
    cout << "size: " << arr.getSize() << ";  " << "numOfElemnts: " << arr.getNumberOfElements() << endl;
    cout << "array: ";
    for(int i=0; i<arr.getNumberOfElements(); i++){
        cout << " " << arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}


int main() {

    DynamicArray<int> arr(5);
    printIntArray(arr);



    arr.insert(1);
    arr.insert(2);
    arr.insert(3);
    printIntArray(arr);

    arr.insert(4);
    printIntArray(arr);

    arr.insert(5);
    printIntArray(arr);

    arr.insert(6);
    printIntArray(arr);

    arr.insert(7);
    arr.insert(8);
    arr.insert(9);
    printIntArray(arr);

    arr.insert(16);
    printIntArray(arr);

    arr[9] = 901;
    arr[0] = 101;
    printIntArray(arr);
```

**valgrind shows me this error- when the destructor is compiled as comment:

```
==3954== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3954==    at 0x4A07192: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
==3954==    by 0x40103E: DynamicArray<int>::insert(int) (DynamicArray.h:41)
==3954==    by 0x400DBC: main (main.cpp:44)**
```

Can anybody tell me what I was doing wrong? am I misusing "delete[]"? or the destructor?

thanks

Comment: You have a Rule of Three violation on your hands. [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) Glad you asked! Click the link and find out.

Comment: why are you `delete`-ing in `insert()`?

Comment: Because Asker is about to replace the old array with a bigger one.

Comment: i think i need to free the space i used to store the data of the first (smaller) array

Comment: You think correctly. Unrelated: consider replacing `arrayOutOfBoundsException` with a `std::range_error`. Not only do you have less to code, but you now have the same behaviour as the standard library.

Comment: @user4581301 The violation should cause a double free if he ever copies a `DynamicArray`, but it doesn't seem like it should cause a leak.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. Can you add the code you're using to exercise the array trimmed down to the case that is causing the leak?

Comment: @Barmar agreed. I could have worded that comment better.

Comment: I've just added the main program i am running =]

Comment: `void printIntArray(DynamicArray<int> arr)` is pass by value. It copies the array resulting in the Rule of Three violation and eventually the double delete Barmar 's talking about. It is possible that before the double delete the program crashes, though. Add extra `cout`s  to track the execution or step through the program with the debugging software that came with your development environment to see if it dies early before it can delete an allocation.

Comment: By "valgrind shows me this error- when the destructor is compiled as comment:" do you mean that `~DynamicArray()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }` is commented out? If so, that's your leak. The problem you likely were debugging before that is probably the Rule of Three violation.

Comment: yea, i meant the destructor was commented out, but thats only because when it was not commented out i got 65 other valgrind errors :S

Comment: OK. Answer forthcoming, but you NEED that destructor. Without it you get that one leak. The leaks you get WITH the destructor are most likely because the program crashed before all of the stuff the runtime has going in the background was cleaned up and put away correctly.

Comment: ok i added copy constructor and operator= and uncommented the destructor and now valgrind says 0 errors!! but the my operator= looks like that: "DynamicArray& operator= (const DynamicArray& da) = delete;"... is that ok? if its deleted that still means there is no rule of the three violation?

Comment: Yes, but only because the object can no longer be assigned. I'll have the answer up in another minute or so. Sounds like you might not need it though. Frankly that's what we really like to see here: No question because you figured it out on your own.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour described by the asker is impossible or

> when the destructor is compiled as comment:

means the destructor has been commented out and this is causing the leak. This has been confirmed in a comment. Without the destuctor the last allocation will never be put away.

## The Asker's real problem is a Rule of Three Violation.

The short version goes something like this:

If a class requires a user defined copy constructor, assignment operator, or  destructor it almost always requires all three.

More on that here: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

In this case,

```
void printIntArray(DynamicArray<int> arr)
```

accepts `arr` by value. This means arr is a copy of the value passed in. In the absence of a custom copy constructor the `arr` inside `printIntArray` will point to the same allocation as the source. The copy will be destroyed at the end of `printIntArray`, and the destructor will delete the allocation, leaving the source pointing to invalid memory so...

```
DynamicArray<int> arr(5); // allocated storage inside arr
printIntArray(arr); // made a copy of arr that points to same storage. 
                    // Storage freed when copy destroyed

arr.insert(1); // invokes undefined behaviour writing into invalid memory
arr.insert(2); // same
arr.insert(3); // same
printIntArray(arr); // copies arr again. This copy is pointing to the same invalid memory
                    // and will try to free the allocation a second time when the 
                    // copy is destroyed
```

The program will almost certainly crash here, making it impossible to leak from the users code. But because the program crashed, Crom only knows what behind-the-scenes structures the runtime was using were not correctly put away.

Whatever happened, as of

```
arr.insert(1);
```

the program was deep in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and whatever happens after that is anybody's guess. Memory leaks are the least of your worries.

## Fixing: Satisfy the Rule of Three

Implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator ([We'll ignore the Rule of Five for now.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three))

You could change

```
void printIntArray(DynamicArray<int> arr)
```

to pass by reference

```
void printIntArray(DynamicArray<int> & arr)
```

and then

```
DynamicArray(const DynamicArray &) = delete;
DynamicArray& operator=(const DynamicArray &) = delete;
```

and disable all copying, but this seems a bit draconian.

Instead [lets use Copy and Swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) because it's simple and easy to understand. Note that it can also be inefficient, so it's not always the right tool. Here it fits what we want.

```
DynamicArray(const DynamicArray & src)  :
        size(src.size), numOfElements(src.numOfElements), arr(new T[size])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = src.arr[i];
    }
}


DynamicArray& operator=(const DynamicArray src)
{
    std::swap(size, src.size);
    std::swap(numOfElements, src.numOfElements);
    std::swap(arr, src.arr);
    return *this;
}
```

And because who wants to copy they don't need to we'll still

```
void printIntArray(DynamicArray<int> & arr)
```

as soon as we're done testing that the copy constructor works correctly.